# Where have all the mixer controls gone?

Tags: windows-vista, audio, mixer

Back in the pre-Vista times the soundcard drivers provided additional controls in the Windows mixer applet, like bass, treble, panning or phantom power for the microphone.

But now I don't find anything except the volume sliders on any Vista workstation (I checked different audio hardware and drivers).

Don't the Vista drivers provide the additional settings or were they abandoned by the manufacturers? Or did Microsoft removed the API support for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Realtek Sound Card drivers still come with a software application that allows you to change the settings.

In Windows 7 and Vista any special settings (if supported) can be changed in the Control Panel:

> Hardware and Sound > Sound

Or in the Classic View:

> Sound

The Sound window will pop up.

[image: sound dialog window under Vista]

Click on the relevant tab (Playback, Recording or Sounds) and it will display attached devices for you to adjust the properties of.

Comment: One more step that was left off: Navigate to the "Levels" tab, that should have all your controls.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this settings depends on drivers and additional application from sound card manufacturer, always.